# Please, make the contents of the page occupy the whole page width, or at least make the code windows resizable

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, usability, code

Please, make the contents of the page occupy the whole page width, or at least make the code windows resizeable.

Comment: You might want to add a "why". How would it improve the site?

Comment: It would make wide code much easier to read.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - If your code samples are so long, I would argue that they are hard to read regardless.

Comment: @Oded - not *my* code samples (which I usually keep to <120 chars and reformat for SO as needed) - *others'* code samples (which they don't bother to reformat).

Comment: @Cyborgx37 - Fair enough. My point is that such long lines of code already suffer from readability. Making the the listing window wider will not help in that regard.

Comment: @Oded - Normally would agree, though not every language is as flexible when it comes to whitespace formatting. Some regex flavors, for example, do not allow arbitrary whitespace, sometimes leading to lines longer then can be accomodated by the current screen width. Non-trivial, heavily nested HTML (with indentation) can suffer the same situation.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this would be a good upgrade to the site. 
The key here,

### Keep it simple.

If your code is too long it is already *hard to read*. Split your code on multiple lines and make it in a readable format. Don't forget we don't want to spend hours trying to figure out what you did.

Stack Overflow have the best formatting tools I've seen on any site and I can think of almost a 100 things I would change before that.

Also, don't you think these informations are relevant ?

[image]

I can't think of a way to make the code blocks resizable without killing the whole interface design.

I mean ... **really ?**

[image]

Comment: I agree to a large extent, but keep in mind that not all languages allow arbitrary whitespace. Some regex flavors, for example, are quite sensitive to misplaced spaces. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3466868/211627

Comment: I agree. But *most of the time* the allowed space is enough. Also the question you linked is pretty clear and perfectly formatted.

Comment: It's the answers which contain regexes longer than the screen. But I agree that these are exceptional and not enough of a reason to change the formatting of SO.