# Expand the horizontal viewing area of Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, design

The original Stack Overflow question/answer viewing area is too skinny to show the complete code at once, and it doesn't expand with respect to the width of the browser. I'd like to expand the viewing area by somehow "dragging and increasing" the viewing area so that all the code is shown at once. Can this feature be implemented?

[image: example of a post where the code has lines which are too long]

Comment: This has been brought up numerous times before. But was declined every single time. I could personally view 3 questions next to each other on my monitor, so your screenshot doesn't look too bad to me.

Comment: There are a lot of duplicates for this, but as far as I can tell, they're mostly _really_ old (6+, some even 12 years old). A small assortment: [Please, make the contents of the page occupy the whole page width, or at least make the code windows resizable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179729) | [Allow code snippets to use more screen width](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187920) | [Are there any plans for SE sites to support variable width layout?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137408)

Comment: Got it. The main reason is long code is hard to read. So I better line-breaking the code rather than dragging the window. Good to know.